# Simple jQuery not working in PHP page online

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a Registration page. Everything seems fine when I'm testing it offline, but when I uploaded the page, the jQuery code for the show-hide of div is not working anymore.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="list" value="1" onchange="valueChanged()"><label>Include me in your mailing list</label>
        <div id="group" style="display:none;">
            <input type="checkbox"><label>Turf</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><label>Landcare</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><label>Landscaping</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><label>Landscaping Architects</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox"><label>Nurseries</label>
        </div>
```

Here is the jQuery script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function valueChanged()
    {
        if($('#list').is(":checked"))
            $("#group").show(300);
        else
            $("#group").hide(300);
            $("#group").children().prop('checked', false);
    }
    </script>
```

I also had a reCaptcha included, does it affect my code?

Comment: Any errors in your debug console?

Comment: check for errors using developer tools (f12 in windows)

Comment: There seems to be none. I'll be checking it later, I have a meeting with my boss. Thanks a lot guys